# Query from Cloud Firestore using UID - No Return No Error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm quite new to flutter and dart. I have started to build an app to help understand the languages better. So far I can authenticate users, log them in, log them out and perform actions based on the status of the user etc.... but I have been struggling for hours on something that I imagine is quite a basic concept. I have tried countless code examples from SO and Flutter Dev but nothing seems to work.

I want to query my Cloud Firestore, searching for any documents that have the document name of 'uid' that matches the current logged in users user ID. This code brings me no errors in Android Studio, and the app runs fine and displays the 'page' but does not redirect or print anything.

As this is really just saying if it's empty do x but if it's not empty do y - even if the syntax was wrong (even though AndroidStuid says it's valid) I would still expect it to change the path to either 'Home' or 'Hometwo' and print one of the two statements, but it does nothing.

If I simply print 'user' it does this ok, and displays the current users ID - but seems to 'break' when querying the collection?

What am I doing wrong here?

```
void checkCurrentUser() async {
    // final FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final user = await _auth.currentUser.uid;
    if (user == null) {
      navigateToSubPageMyAccount(context);
    } else {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('samplecollection')
          .doc(user)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          navigateToSubPageHome(context);
          print('Document exists on the database: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        } else {
          navigateToSubPageHomeTwo(context);
          print('Document does not exist');
      }
      });
    }
  }
```

Update:

I found the answer as per my comment below. If anyone else stumbles upon this thread, the reason none of this code was working is because I had commented it out in error from within initState during some other testing:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // checkCurrentUser();
  }
```

...and simply removed the commenting so it was included when the app ran:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkCurrentUser();
  }
```

Comment: "If I simply print 'user' it does this ok, and displays the current users ID" Can you add this code, and its output, to the question? While at it, please then also show the output from the other print statement. Finally, can you also add a screenshot of the document you expect to get back?

Comment: I've found the problem. Thanks for the reply, this helped me find the root cause. I added the print 'user' code and it didn't work (when it had before). I realised I had commented out 'checkCurrentUser()' in initState through all the testing I did - as soon as I removed the commenting and ran the app it worked as expected. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out!

Comment: Hi @cc976a, good work finding the solution! Could you post an answer and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to accept it, as no one has provided an answer. I have checked online and without an answer from someone, I don't think I can accept this or mark it as answered or complete (?)